# marshmallow custom "Validator" function not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, marshmallow

I create  marshmallow [custom field](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_fields.html#creating-a-field-class)
like bellow:

```py
from marshmallow.fields import Field

class CustomFiled(Field):
    def _serialize(self, value, attr, obj, **kwargs):
        pass

    def _deserialize(self, value, attr, data, **kwargs):
        pass
```

and then create [custom validator](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshmallow.validate.html), like bellow:

```py
from marshmallow import ValidationError

def customValidation(value):
    # why value is None, not "some value here" ??
    print("value:", value)

    if value is None:
        raise ValidationError("custom_field cannot be None!")
```

and the main code to begin validation:

```py
from marshmallow import ValidationError, Schema

def main():
    try:
        data = {
            "custom_field": "some value here"
        }
        schema = {
            "custom_field": CustomFiled(required=True, validate=customValidation)
        }

        # validation begin
        ma_schema = Schema.from_dict(schema)
        ma_schema().load(data)

        # if no error occurs, then validation success
        print("Validation Success! :)")
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(e.messages)

'''
output on terminal:
    value: None
    {'custom_field': ['custom_field cannot be None!']}
'''
main()
```

this full source code:

```py
from marshmallow.fields import Field
from marshmallow import ValidationError, Schema


class CustomFiled(Field):
    def _serialize(self, value, attr, obj, **kwargs):
        pass

    def _deserialize(self, value, attr, data, **kwargs):
        pass


def customValidation(value):
    # why value is None, not "some value here" ??
    print("value:", value)

    if value is None:
        raise ValidationError("custom_field cannot be None!")


def main():
    try:
        data = {
            "custom_field": "some value here"
        }
        schema = {
            "custom_field": CustomFiled(required=True, validate=customValidation)
        }

        # validation begin
        ma_schema = Schema.from_dict(schema)
        ma_schema().load(data)

        # if no error occurs, then validation success
        print("Validation Success! :)")
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(e.messages)

'''
output on terminal:
    value: None
    {'custom_field': ['custom_field cannot be None!']}
'''
main()
```

why arg `value` on function `customValidation()` is `None` not `"some value here"` ?

what i suppose ouput on terminal:

> "value: some value here"

> "Validation Success! :)"

But when im try using build-in validator (Str). arg `value` on `customValidator(value)` is printed . Here is the code:

```py
from marshmallow.fields import Str
from marshmallow import ValidationError, Schema

def supposed():
    def customValidator(value):
        print("value: ", value)

    try:
        data = {
            "name": "candra"
        }
        schema = {
            "name": Str(validate=customValidator)
        }

        # validation begin
        ma_schema = Schema.from_dict(schema)
        ma_schema().load(data)

        # if no error occurs, then validation success
        print("Validation Success! :)")
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(e.messages)

'''
Terminal output:
    value:  candra
    Validation Success! :)
'''
supposed()
```

Output on terminal:

> value: candra

> Validation Success! :)

Here, `candra` is taken from `data = {'name': 'candra'}` that passed by `schema = { "name": Str(validate=customValidator) }`

Answer (score 0):

i'm eventually realize what the mistake, the override method `_deserialize()` is void (return None), it should return value to be pass on `customValidation()`

here the code:

```py
class CustomFiled(Field):
    def _deserialize(self, value, attr, data, **kwargs):
        return value


def main():
    def customValidation(value):
        print("value:", value)

    try:
        data = {
            "custom_field": "some value here"
        }
        schema = {
            "custom_field": CustomFiled(required=True, validate=customValidation)
        }

        # validation begin
        ma_schema = Schema.from_dict(schema)
        ma_schema().load(data)

        # if no error occurs, then validation success
        print("Validation Success! :)")
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(e.messages)

main()
```

and the output is:

> "value: some value here"

> "Validation Success! :)"

how stupid i was